# Best way to capture paused video frame to canvas

Tags: javascript, scroll, html5-canvas, html5-video, pause

I know how to copy on frame by frame basis from a playing HTML5 video to a canvas using 2D context.

But I want to work with a paused video, change dinamically its `currentTime` and copy current frame of video to canvas.

My guess is some process is not called yet when video position is set with `currentTime` property, although the video itself does update the image it shows (but not to the canvas).

I've found that it's posible to overcome this by setting a setTimeout to do the canvas ´drawImage´ in the next step.

[You can see here a jsfiddle that proves the point](https://jsfiddle.net/4emfhLw3/2/).

As you can see in the fiddle you can play the video, and canvas updates, but if you pause the video, mouse scroll moves `currentTime` of video. There, a ´seTimeout´ is needed to update the canvas, if I call the `drawImage` method directly, canvas doesn't update.

**In short, my question is:**

Is there a better way to do this? Is it posible to do this without setTimeout and inside de loop itself? Pros & Cons?

Thank you very much for reading through here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you change the `currentTime` of your VideoElement, a [seeked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/seeked) Event will trigger when the video actually changed its position.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("v");
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var targetFrame = document.getElementById('t');
var cw = canvas.width = 200;
var ch = canvas.height = Math.round(cw / 1.7777);
var targetOffset = 0;

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  targetOffset = targetOffset + (e.deltaY / 1000);
  targetFrame.value = targetOffset;
  seek(); // for demo purpose, we only listen to wheel
  return false;
});
// that's all is needed
vid.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
  context.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, cw, ch);
});
// for demo
// removed the rendering loop
// now it only changes the video's currentTime property
function seek() {
  targetOffset = targetOffset * 0.9;
  targetFrame.value = Math.round(targetOffset * 100) / 100;
  var vct = vid.currentTime - targetOffset;
  if (vct < 0) {
    vct = vid.duration + vct;
  } else if (vct > vid.duration) {
    vct = vct - vid.duration;
  }
  vid.currentTime = vct;
}
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#c {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  scroll up is forward
</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div>
      Video element:
    </div>
    <video controls height="120" id="v" tabindex="-1" autobuffer="auto" preload="auto">
    <source type="video/webm" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.webm"/>
</video>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>
      Canvas element:
    </div>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <div>
      Momentum: <input type=text id="t">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That just solved my problem! I ended only adding `vid.addEventListener('seeked', function() { context.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, cw, ch); });` and keeping everything else inside the loop, as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4emfhLw3/3/)